# Kafka Messages - Producer & Consumer Client in Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Thanks for your help in advance.

I want to push and pull messages in the following format in Kafka broker.

```
<header>
  <version></version>
  <id></id>
</header>
  <detail>
     <firstname></firstname>
     <lastname></lastname>
     <salary></salary>
  </detail>
```

Producer client in Java should be able to push in this format and Consumer client should be able to read and parse this message. How can I do this? Are there any particular methods to do this in Kafka Java API?

I already wrote producer and consumer java client to push and pull simple text messages.

Really appreciate your help.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Kafka is agnostic about the message payload so this should work just fine. What you have there looks like a simple text message.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for a way to serialise/deserialise object to/from XML. If that's the case I would suggest you to look at Jackson https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml.